# How to subclass or store extra information in AVAudioPlayer player objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, subclassing

I need to create a new NSNumber or integer property called `primaryKey` to be included with all [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) objects that I create so that I can read the value of that property within the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` callback and know exactly which database record was played.

The reason I need to do this is: I can't use the player [URL property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/url) to determine which database record it was since the same sound file can be used multiple times within the playlist.

How can I add a new property to an existing iOS class like this?

---

Example:

```
AVAudioPlayer *newAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];  

self.theAudio = newAudio; // automatically retain audio and dealloc old file if new file is loaded
if (theAudio != nil) [audioPlayers addObject:theAudio];

[newAudio release];

[theAudio setDelegate: theDelegate];
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops: 0];
[theAudio setVolume: callVolume];

// This is the new property that I want to add
[theAudio setPrimaryKey: thePrimaryKey];

[theAudio play];
```

Then I'd retrieve it in the callback like this:

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag 
{    
   NSNumber *finishedSound = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[player primaryKey]];

   // Do something with this information now...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a subclass and add your property just like you would when subclassing anything.

### Interface

```
@interface MyAudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer

@property (nonatomic) int primaryKey;

@end
```

### Implementation

```
@implementation MyAudioPlayer

@synthesize primaryKey = _primaryKey;

@end
```

### Creating

```
MyAudioPlayer *player = [[MyAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.primaryKey = thePrimaryKey;
...
```

### Delegate

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    if ([player isKindOfClass:[MyAudioPlayer class]]) {
        MyAudioPlayer *myPlayer = (MyAudioPlayer *)player;
        NSNumber *primaryKeyObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myPlayer.primaryKey];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob!  This is exactly what I was hoping you could do.  I'm still learning about subclassing, but this makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: Quick question: Why couldn't I just do `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(MyAudioPlayer *)player` instead so I don't have to cast the player into a `MyAudioPlayer` object?

Comment: You can, if you're sure the receiver of that message will only be the delegate for `MyAudioPlayer` objects, and not for plain `AVAudioPlayer` objects.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach might be to create an NSMutableDictionary and use the AVAudioPlayers you create as KEYS with the primary key (or an entire dictionary) as the corresponding VALUE. Then when a player stops playing (or errors) you can look it up in your dictionary and recover anything you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't want to create the extra work of managing another dictionary.

Comment: Fair enough, but managing a dictionary seems easier than creating a new subclass.